# How to center multiple form elements horizontally and vertically on frame?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

### Problem

I've consulted both this [resource](http://vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/) and this [resource](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/), however my form elements are still not centering like they should (I've tried flex, I've tried padding, I've tried stretching, etc). I want both form fields to center both vertically and horizontally on the screen.

I've wrapped my form elements in a div, yet it's still not working. If anyone could let me know how to do this it would be greatly appreciated!

[image]
I want the fields to appear under each other. And I want the fields to be vertically and horizontally centered on the screen.

### Code

```css
body {
    background: #3472FF;
    color: white;
}

.closeBtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: white;
}

.login {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.field {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
 <button class="closeBtn"><span class="icon-x"></span></button>
    <form action="form.php" method="post">
        <div class="login">
            <div class="field">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"> </div>
            <div class="field">
                <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password"> </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

`flex-direction: column;` and `height: 100%` for almost all elements do the trick:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #3472FF;
  color: white;
}

.closeBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
}

form {
  height: 100%;
}

.login {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.field {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="closeBtn"><span class="icon-x"></span></button>
<form action="form.php" method="post">
  <div class="login">
    <div class="field">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"> </div>
    <div class="field">
      <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password"> </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:
          `top: 0;`
right: 0;
          `bottom: 0;`
left: 0;
on your CSS